# Nextcloud conf not loading correct page

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost

I have got nextcloud working in a VirtualHost (See configuation below). When I only have on virtualhost (nextcloud.conf) enabled in Apache on Ubuntu 16.04, it works.  But when I enable the 000-default.conf and the default-ssl.conf it keeps taking me to the main page not the nextcloud page. I have posted all my configuation files. I want to get the default virtualhosts working because I want to catch all urls that don't match the nextcloud config.

nextcloud.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName storage.declanmarks.pw

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^storage.declanmarks.pw
        RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
        #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://storage.declanmarks.pw$1 [R,L]      
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        Alias /files /var/www/files
        ServerName storage.declanmarks.pw
        DocumentRoot /var/www/nextcloud/
        ServerAlias storage.declanmarks.pw

        <Directory /var/www/nextcloud/>
                Options +FollowSymlinks
                AllowOverride All

                <IfModule mod_dav.c>
                        Dav off
                </IfModule>

                SetEnv HOME /var/www/nextcloud
                SetEnv HTTP_HOME /var/www/nextcloud
        </Directory>

        # SSL
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/storage.declanmarks.pw/cert.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/storage.declanmarks.pw/privkey.pem
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/storage.declanmarks.pw/fullchain.pem

        Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains;"

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

default-ssl.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:443>   
        DocumentRoot /var/www/main

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # SSL
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/storage.declanmarks.pw/cert.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/storage.declanmarks.pw/privkey.pem
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/storage.declanmarks.pw/fullchain.pem

</VirtualHost>
```

000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/main

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What result you want? I see NexCloud login on `storage.declanmarks.pw`.

Comment: @AlexanderTolkachev I have just enabled the default-ssl and 000-default site and it keeps taking me to a temp page that I created.